# getting data from 5 tables

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 5 tables:  `tblbook`,`tblauthor`,`tblpublisher`,`tblauthorbook`,`tblbookpublisher`

- `tblbook` has the columns:

  - `BookID`,
  - `Barcode`,
  - `ISBN`,
  - `BookSection`and
  - `BookCopyNumber`
- `tblauthor`:

  - `AuthorID`,
  - `AuthorName`
- `tblpublisher`

  - `publisherID`
  - `publishername`
- `tblauthorbook`

  - `AuthorID`
  - `BookID`
- `tblbookpublisher`

  - `publisherID`
  - `BookID`

What i need to do is to show in the listview all the books that is equal to the inputed barcodenumber in `vbnet`, along with their `authorname` and `publisher`.

Im confused as to how should i do this and this is the query that i tried:

```
"Select tblbook.BookID, 
   tblbook.BookTitle,
   tblbook.BookSection,
   tblauthorbook.AuthorID,
   tblauthorbook.BookID,
   tblauthor.AuthorID,
   tblauthor.AuthorName,
   tblbookpublisher.PublisherID,
   tblbookpublisher.BookID,
   tblpublisher.PublisherID,
   tblbook.AcSecCode 
 from tblbook, 
   tblauthorbook, 
   tblauthor, 
   tblbookpublisher, 
   tblpublisher 
 where tblbook.Barcode = '" & txtbarcode.Text & "' 
   and tblbook.BookID = tblauthorbook.BookID 
   and tblauthorbook.AuthorID = tblauthor.AuthorID 
   and tblbook.BookID = tblbookpublisher.BookID 
   and tblbookpublisher.PublisherID = tblpublisher.PublisherID"
```

There's no error but it doesn't show anything on my listview so my query must be wrong. can someone help me how should i query this correctly? Thank You in advance

Comment: Don't concatenate strings from a form into SQL; this is SQL Injection vulnerable. Also, don't join by "table, table, table"; use inner/left joins (lookup ANSI-92 joins in SQL). Lastly, if the SQL produces results in SQL Server Management Studio (presuming Microsoft SQL Server), the problem is in your vb.net code and we would need to see that.

Comment: Check the Properties window of the ListView. The View property should be set to Details if you are trying to display sub-items.